# internet explorer causing issue with layout

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am having basic problem with my application in Internet Explorer. In all other major browsers Chrome, Safari, opera and Firefox, I have not got this layout problem in other major browsers but in internet explorer I do.

[Open Application (Internet Explorer)](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text11.php)

Problem

How come the last table column is displayed underneath and not next to the last table column? Below is the code:

```
$outputform.=" 
<form action='QandATable.php' method='post' id='sessionForm'>
<table>
<tr>
<th>9: Room and Building:</th>
<th>Building: {$buildingHTML}</th>
<th>Room: {$roomHTML}</th>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
";

echo $outputform;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE don't like HTML error's, in you case you have a closed form tag inside a th tag:

```
<form action='QandATable.php' method='post' id='sessionForm'>
<table>
<tr>
<th>9: Room and Building:</th>
<th>Building: <select name="buildings" id="buildingsDrop" onchange="getRooms();">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value='Canalside East'>Canalside East</option>
<option value='Canalside West'>Canalside West</option>
</select></form></th>
<th>Room: <select name="rooms" id="roomsDrop">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
</select></th>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```

I am talking about this  tag:

```
</select></form></th>
```

Table will be fine after excess form tag is removed. I have tested it with your HTMl source.

Comment: found same thing by quickly running page through W3C validator. @user1881090 this is also why your ajax not working in IE in your other question

Comment: Thanks, I will have to validate my pages then :)